In praat, the number of segments not match the calculations when MFCC coeficients are bein calculated, always resulting in one less segment
I am calculating MFCC coeficientes for 3 seconds of audio. The configuration is as follows: number of coefficients = 12, window size = 30 ms, and hop size = 30 ms. I expect 100 segments with 12 coefficients with this configuration, but I only obtain 99 segments. What is the reason?
